# What actually is the difference with what happened here

Tags: integration

What actually is the difference with what happened here?

$\int(x+1)^2$
$\mathrm{dx}$ =$\frac{(x+1)^3} {3}+\mathrm{C} $

$\int (x^2+2x+1)\mathrm{dx} $= $\frac{x^3} {3} +x^2+x+\mathrm {C}$

$\frac{x^3} {3} +x^2+x \ne \frac{(x+1)^3} {3} $

I started working on first-order differential equations and I'm kind of confused with the one to make use of.

Comment: Those are not the same $C$: in the solution of the second integral the constant term arising from developing $\frac{(x+1)^3}{3}$ is absorbed in the constant.

Comment: @Duca_Conte Which one would you have me choose in this case?

Comment: Either answer is correct because $\dfrac{(x+1)^3}3+C_1=\dfrac{x^3}3+x^2+x+C_2$ when $\dfrac13+C_1=C_2$

Comment: They are not the same, but you can see that they have the same derivative, and as such, they differ by a constant.  When you make use of the information describing initial value, then you will know which constant to use (e.g. if the question says _Find $f(x)$ if $f'(x)=(x+1)^2$ and $f(2)=3$_, then you can solve for $C=-6$).

Comment: Alright. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why I generally think it's preferable to work with definite integrals. Indefinite integrals do not represent unique functions. Indefinite integration can probably be best thought of as an operation that sends a function to a set of functions, (the set of functions whose derivative is our input, which by the mean value theorem we can show to all differ by a constant) with an arithmetic defined on them. There are complications with treating them as single valued, and you can derive some apparent contradictions by mishandling the "constant of integration". Definite integrals do not have the same issue.

With that the question really boils down to if:

$$\left\{\frac {(x + 1)^3} 3 + C_1:C_1\in \mathbb R\right\}$$

is the same set as:

$$\left\{\frac {x^3} 3 + x^2 + x + C_2:C_2 \in \mathbb R\right\}$$

We can see that it is, as stated in the comments, writing:

$$C_2 = \frac 1 3 + C_1$$

so there is no issue here.